# Remove the lower priority duplicated objects in array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

### PROBLEM

I have an array like this one:

```
  [
      {
          cardId: "4908r920-2394930-3302-222",
          power: 3 
      },
      {
          cardId: "4908r920-2394930-3302-222",
          power: 10
      },
      {
          cardId: "6666640-92011-3302-888",
          power: 932
      },
      {
          cardId: "4908r920-2394930-3302-222",
          power: 5
      },
      {
          cardId: "6666640-92011-3302-888", 
          power: 9
      }
  ]
```

As you can see, in this array there are two different cards:

> The card which id is "4908r920-2394930-3302-222" and the other one which id is "6666640-92011-3302-888"

These cards have a different power, but they are duplicated in the array by the field cardId.

### QUESTION

I need to remove the lower power repeated cards, I mean, the final array has to be as follows:

```
 [
      {
          cardId: "4908r920-2394930-3302-222",
          power: 10
      },
      {
          cardId: "6666640-92011-3302-888",
          power: 932
      }
 ]
```

Any ideas? I would appreciate if the solution was in +ES6.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

simply that , with array reduce

```js
const Arr1 = 
      [ { cardId: "4908r920-2394930-3302-222", power:   3 } 
      , { cardId: "4908r920-2394930-3302-222", power:  10 } 
      , { cardId: "6666640-92011-3302-888",    power: 932 } 
      , { cardId: "4908r920-2394930-3302-222", power:   5 } 
      , { cardId: "6666640-92011-3302-888",    power:   9 } 
      ] 
const Arr2 = Arr1.reduce((acc,{cardId,power})=>
      {
      let card = acc.find(x=>x.cardId===cardId)
      if      (!card)            acc.push({cardId,power})
      else if (card.power<power) card.power=power
      return acc
      },[])
      
console.log( Arr2 )
```